# Node Js - Session value get from another file

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am developing website and using nodejs (express) + postgresql.
I want to use session value for all files. i added the my code.

app.js

```
var session = require('express-session');
var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();
require('./conversation/conversation')(app);
```

//routes/index.js

```
 var sess;

    router.post('/login, function(req, res) {
     sess = req.session;
     sess.userId = 8;
    });

    router.get('/test1', function(req, res) {

        sess = req.session;
        var userId = sess.userId;
        console.log(userId);
    // output 8
    });
```

//conversation/conversation.js

```
router.get('/test2', function(req, res) {
    sess = req.session;
    var userId = sess.userId;
    console.log(userId);
// get userId is undefined
});
```

- First I run login method. In that time session will be created.
  UserId = 8.
- Then I run test1 method. I get the session values.
- Then I run the test2 method(but the test2 method is conversation
  file). I get undefined value.  How can I access the session values in
  coversation.js

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(session({
  cookieName: 'session',
  secret: 'random_string_goes_here',
  duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
  activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
}));
```